# Close jQuery hide/show div on load?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a jQuery hide/show div script for the FAQ portion of my page.

Everything works great except the questions are opened upon loading and I would like them to be closed.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.faq-row-head a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('opened');
        $(this).parents('.faq-row').find('.faq-row-entry').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('.faq-close').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.faq-row').find('.opened').removeClass('opened');
        $(this).parents('.faq-row').find('.faq-row-entry').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Here

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the first line:

```
$(".faq-div").hide();
```

Comment: While normally I prefer a CSS solution to a situation like this, the big advantage is for non-JavaScript users.  A user without JavaScript can't reveal the hidden content.  However, if JavaScript is also used to hide the content, then a user without JavaScript enabled has access to all the content because it's never hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Have the row entries hidden by default. Adding a `style="display: none"` attribute will do what you want.

Comment: Hey, I am sort of new to jQuery, where would I enter that attribute?

Comment: In the element itself. Like `<div style="display: none">`

Answer (score 0):

first use the below line  while  loading ..

$(this).parents('.faq-row').find('.faq-row-entry').hide();

try it once ..i'm not sure .

Comment: Hey, i tried this and it stayed open on click and when you closed it, it would not open again. hmmmm

Comment: you asked for how to add attribute right ..regarding @nornagon answer 

here it is  ..if i guess correctly ..

$(.faq-row-entry).attr('style',"diaply-none");

Answer (score 0):

Move all the scripts to end of your html/jsp and then try to add this in first line of $(document).ready function :

```
$(".faq-row-entry").hide();
```